# Computation of irreducible characters for $S_n$ - Mathematica vs. GAP

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups, gap, mathematica

For some physical applications I need the knowledge of irreducible characters for symmetric groups $S_n$ with large $n$. For small ones I was using `FiniteGroupData` in Mathematica, but this is limited to $n=10$. For larger $n$ I am using GAP: `Display(CharacterTable(SymmetricGroup(n)));` (cf. [Mathematica-stackexchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/245447/charactertable-for-symmetric-groups-s-n-with-large-n)).

The result obtained by these two methods differ by signs. I was trying to find the origin of these differences in documentation of these programs but I didn't find the answer. Why the results from Mathematica (which agree with D. M. Jackson "Tables of Irreducible Characters of the Symmetric Group on at most Fifteen Symbols" 1988; see also [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9306022)) differ from ones which are produced by using GAP? It is almost true that the difference is at even positions in the tables, but this pattern is not exact. Does anyone know how to convert GAP's result into the same convention as used in Mathematica?

Comment: Are you taking into account the order of conjugacy classes?

Comment: Furthermore, `CharacterTable(SymmetricGroup(n))` will calculate new table for each new object given as an argument. If randomised methods are involved (maybe not for symmetric groups, but for some others this is true), the order of classes may differ even for different runs. For symmetric groups, you may wish to use the CTblLib package, which gives the character tables library, and call it like `CharacterTable("S5")`, `CharacterTable("S10")`, etc.

Comment: Can you tell a bit more what "Jackson's tables from '88" are. Presumably you are not talking about the King of Pop.

Comment: @ahulpke, I added the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it is highly unlikely that the tables really differ, but the issue is most likely an arrangement of classes and characters.

`CharacterTable(SymmetricGroup(n))` will take $S_n$ as a group and calculate the character table with generic methods (that might be somewhat adapted. There is no guarantee about the arrangement.

`CharacterTable("S10")` takes the table from the character table library. Here class/character arrangement is made to be compatible with the ATLAS of finite groups.

You probably want to use the parameterized constructor
`CharacterTable("Symmetric",10)`. This uses the Murnaghan-Nakayama relations to calculate the table. Most crucial (assuming the variable `c` holds the table), you can use
`ClassParameters(c)` and `CharacterParameters(c)` to get the partitions corresponding to the classes, respectively characters. This will probably allow you to translate to the convention in other publications.

Comment: I will check if the difference is only in the order. An example for $n=3$ is posted in the answer to a question for which I added the link in this question.

Comment: A follow-up question: How large $n$ is included the character table library in GAP? Can the  method 'CharacterTable(SymmetricGroup(n))' be used to compute such tables for larger $n$, say of the order of one hundred, or is it too time-consuming?

Comment: `CharacterTable("S19")` works but `CharacterTable("S20")` not, so one has to compute it differently. Using `CharacterTable(SymmetricGroup(50))` takes 700 milliseconds. For $n=60$, already 4 seconds. For $n=70$ - 24 seconds. YMMV.

Comment: The method `CharacterTable(SymmetricGroup(n))` will scale with the order of the group ($n!$) and is likely limited to n up to 20 or 30. The method `CharacterTable("Symmetric",10)` effectively evaluates formulas that give the entries of the table and thus should scale closer to the size of the character table. I've never tried a hunded, but I don't see a reason why not.

Comment: I tried to use the code proposed in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/245482/36731 and by using the method `CharacterTable(SymmetricGroup(42))` it took almost 2hours and the resulting .txt file was of order 10GB. Therefore I started to worry about the limitations. So it seems like the problem with time-consuming is not in this method but with the way proposed in the linked question to translate the result into the .txt file. Is this right?

Comment: The problem is likely in the string processing and writing out a huge file. Do you actually need the whole set of table entries, or could you do pre-processing in GAP and then have less data to transfer?

Comment: Actually, what I finally need is the knowledge of expansion coefficients $a_{\mu}$ in (36) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9306022.pdf. Since they appear in the decomposition into Schur functions, are they maybe already implemented in GAP and accessible without computing them "by hand"?  At some point I will need to make some plots out this data, so will need to use Mathematica, but at least some algebraic manipulations can be actually done directly in GAP. I have to think which part exactly can be done in GAP in order to have as small output as possible.

Comment: I have one follow-up question. Suppose for concreteness that $n=6$ and I have given two partitions $\{3,2,1\}$ and $\{4,1,1\}$. Is there a direct way to get $\chi^{\{3,2,1\}}_{\{4,1,1\}}$ using functions implemented in GAP? I can write some some kind of loop `for` where I can search for the positions of these partitions and then use them to get this value, but it seems to be not so optimal solution. Is there a more clever way to get this value having given two partitions as an input?

Comment: There is an undocumented function `CharValueSymmetric(n,beta,pi)` that as far as I can see does this. You might have to try out which partition goes in which place.

Comment: When I tried `CharValueSymmetric(6, [4,1,1], [3,2,1])` and `CharValueSymmetric(6, [3,2,1], [4,1,1])` I got `0` for both of them, but one of them should be equal to $-1$ according to the full table. My understanding was that `beta` and `pi` are the partitions and they have to be inserted in a way I did it, but the result suggests that I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: The function is documented only in how it is used in the code.  You would have to have a look how it gets called (line 422 in `lib/ctblsymm.gi`, calling `BetaSet` on the first partition) for building the character table.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Are the two results really different? A character table is only determined up to ordering of the rows and columns. Did you check if the two results are the same up to such permutations ?