# Obtaining the characters of the symmetric group corresponding to partitions in GAP

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, integer-partitions, gap

Is there a way via the computer algebra system GAP to obtain the irreducible character of the symmetric group $S_n$ (over $\mathbb{C}$) corresponding to a given partition (via the canonical bijection)?
So the input should be a partition and the output should be the corresponding character as a character in GAP (so that one can do things using existing GAP programs like calculating scalar products between characters or multiply two characters).

Comment: See the answer of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4128421/computation-of-irreducible-characters-for-s-n-mathematica-vs-gap?rq=1 that describes how to find the corresponmding partitions.

Comment: @ahulpke Thank you. Is there a direct way to obtain the irreducible characters corresponding to the partition so that one can apply the standard programms of gap like calculating the scalar product of characters? In this thread it seems that the output is just the character table/values but not the characters itself.

Comment: Find the position of the partition in the `CharacterParameters`. Then take the character (from `Irr`) in the same position. (Or do I misunderstand your question?)

Comment: @ahulpke Thanks again for your answer. Does the following do the intended things for a given n: n:=4;;U:=Partitions(n);g:= SymmetricGroup( n );SetName( g, "Sn" );tbl:= CharacterTable( g );irr:= Irr( g );W:=[];for i in [1..Size(U)] do Append(W,[[U[i],irr[i]]]);od;W; ? So the list W is a list of tuples with first entry the partition and the second entry the corresponding irreducible character. I am not 100% it does the right thing but it seems the linked thread suggests that it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This gets too long for comment.) You must use the generic (parameterized) character table for the `"symmetric"` group. And you must use `CharacterParameters`.

In your example:

```
gap> n:=4;;U:=Partitions(n);
[ [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ], [ 2, 1, 1 ], [ 2, 2 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 4 ] ]
gap> tbl:=CharacterTable("symmetric",n);
CharacterTable( "Sym(4)" )
gap> irr:=Irr(tbl);;
gap> cp:=CharacterParameters(tbl);
[ [ 1, [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ] ], [ 1, [ 2, 1, 1 ] ], [ 1, [ 2, 2 ] ], [ 1, [ 3, 1 ] ],
  [ 1, [ 4 ] ] ]
gap> W:=[];;for i in [1..Length(U)] do
> pos:=PositionProperty(cp,x->x[2]=U[i]);
> Add(W,[U[i],irr[pos]]);
> od;
gap> W;
[ [ [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ], Character( CharacterTable( "Sym(4)",[ 1, -1, 1, 1, -1 ] ) ],
  [ [ 2, 1, 1 ], Character( CharacterTable( "Sym(4)" ), [ 3, -1, -1, 0, 1 ] )],
  [ [ 2, 2 ], Character( CharacterTable( "Sym(4)" ),[ 2, 0, 2, -1, 0 ] ) ],
  [ [ 3, 1 ], Character( CharacterTable( "Sym(4)" ), [ 3, 1, -1, 0, -1 ] ) ],
  [ [ 4 ], Character( CharacterTable( "Sym(4)" ), [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ] ) ] ]
```

Comment: Oops. Needs of course `CharacterParameters`. Fixed.